# Custom sort method for column in ReactTable

Tags: reactjs

I want to make a custom sort method for a column in my ReactTable. How can I say to ReactTable that it should use my custom sort method instead?

I can not see how I am supposed to use sortMethod property on the column. When I pass this:

```
sortMethod: (prop1, prop2, prop3) => console.log(prop1, prop2, prop3); //undefined undefined false
```

So I guess that the `prop3` says false because it is not desc. However, what about the `prop1` and `prop2`? should it not be something? One reason can be that I only have an `id` on the column, and no `accessor`?

Answer (score 1):

React-table returns undefined for *props1* and *props2* due to unavailability of accessor key in column props.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table#columns

Answer (score -1):

You can use react-virtualized library for table in reactjs.
It provides sort() method which can be customize. 
Please check this link:-
https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/tableWithNaturalSort.md

I hope this helps.